# Unit Testing a @Query Repository Class

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing

I've got a Repo class in a java spring project, that interacts with a DB (neo4j).

The methods look like this:

```
@Query("call example.method({0})")
String getExampleResult(String id);
```

Since this is a unit test, I will need to mock out the call, but I have no idea how to do this. Anyone with experience here?

Comment: You'd mock it just like you'd mock anything else. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Mock whole repository.

Comment: you just need to inject Mock implementation of repo interface

Comment: Antoniossss, I have already mocked the repo class for the service class that's using it. Can I not mock the calls to the database to test the code inside the repo?